# Constant in PHP class and "static" keyword

Tags: php, oop, constants, php-5.4

Please consider this code:

```
    class App {

        const ALERT_ERROR=1;
        const ALERT_WARN=2;
        const ALERT_INFO=3;

        public static function alert($title,$type=ALERT_ERROR) {        
            switch ($type){
                default:                
                case static::ALERT_ERROR:
                    $class="alert-danger"; break;
                case static::ALERT_WARN:
                    $class="alert-warning"; break;
                case static::ALERT_INFO:
                    $class="alert-info"; break;
            }
            ...
        }
    }
```

I have some trouble with the `static::constant` syntax inside the switch. I some PHP webserver it is recognized as correct value (as defined in `const ALERT_ERROR`) in other server I had to remove the `static::` prefix and leave only the constant name. But with this way the first webserver doesn't work...

The first php version is 5.4.7 the second is 5.4.37... but I don't think this is version problem.

The problem is that if I run this code:

```
App::alert("test",App::ALERT_INFO);
```

the $class is set a "alert-danger" as default, and the App::ALERT_INFO constant is not recognized. If I add static:: prefix the constant is recognized from one webserver and not from the other and viceversa if I remove it.

The notice thrown is: **Use of undefined constant ALERT_ERROR - assumed 'ALERT_ERROR'**

**EDIT after the answer**

The problem was not in the switch cases but in the default parameter. That was assumed as "ALERT_ERROR" string and so only the default switch was got.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I will better explain it in the question... sorry

Comment: Before closing your question try to explain how exactly it's not working

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Comment: *If I add `static:: prefix`* - where?

Comment: @sectus before the constant name, example static::ALERT_INFO instead of simply ALERT_INFO

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to add the static keyword to the constant used as default value.

```
public static function alert($title, $type=static::ALERT_ERROR) {
  // ....
}
```

But `static` is only determined at runtime. So if `static` behaviour is really needed then:

```
public static function alert($title, $type=null) {
  if ($type === null) {
      $type = static::ALERT_ERROR;
  }
  // ...
}
```

If static is not really necessary then replace all `static::` as `self::`

```
   public static function alert($title, $type=self::ALERT_ERROR) {        
    switch ($type){
        default:                
        case self::ALERT_ERROR:
            $class="alert-danger"; break;
        case self::ALERT_WARN:
            $class="alert-warning"; break;
        case self::ALERT_INFO:
            $class="alert-info"; break;
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: "static::" is not allowed in compile-time constants

Comment: This seems to be the answer, but I have to set a different param default value.

Comment: Ok. Do you really need static? If not use `self`. `static` is for inheritance override

Comment: Please edit answer to reflect correct answer, as using static here gives fatal error!

Comment: In this particular case I can also use null as default param because the it is used only in the case switch so it is catched by the "default" case.  Thanks.