# PHP NumberFormatter add grouping for 5+ digit numbers?

Tags: php, numberformatter

I'm trying to fix a formatting error in [the PHP NumberFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter) for my language, Bulgarian: thousands grouping is only introduced for 5+ digit numbers, i.e. "5 000" is wrong.

Is there a predefined constant I can use?

I thought this would be `NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SIZE` but this doesn't take into consideration the above rule. Should I be looking for some other attribute or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

Comment: Not sure if that can be specified using any of the options; you might have to create your own `DecimalFormat` pattern. If you check the explanation on https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1DecimalFormat.html, it shows that a pattern `#,##,##0` applied to the value `123456789` would result in `12,34,56,789` - so your pattern would have to be something like `### #####0` then.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks! This might be too difficult for me but I'll give it a try. However, I noticed in the example description you referred that they mention `grouping_size` and `secondary_grouping_size`. Could these be what I need? The PHP page documentation mentions nothing about their meaning, very unhelpful.

Comment: Just ran a couple of tests using `$num->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SIZE, 4);` and `$num->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::SECONDARY_GROUPING_SIZE, 3);` but the results are not what I need, e.g. the number `2,806,766` is displayed as `280 6766`. I also tried switching the values but the results are still not meaningful.

Comment: Those are just the sizes of the groups to begin with, but they don't specify what separator gets put _between_ the groups. Since you basically want _different_ separators between your groups, that won't help.

Comment: I see. Well, I tried reading about `DecimalFormat` but I couldn't understand how to create my own pattern, so I'll just abandon this issue.

Comment: _"thousands grouping is only introduced for 5+ digit numbers, i.e. "5 000" is wrong"_ - ah, so that means for a longer number, there _will_ be a space before the last three digits? `1 234 567 890` would be correct then? That can't even be done using a pattern formatter, I think - because you would have to apply a _different_ pattern based on the magnitude of the number.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't be possible with `SECONDARY_GROUPING_SIZE` since this parameter applies to groups furthest the first one **IN ALL CASES**.

`$a = new \NumberFormatter("bg-BG", \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$a->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SIZE, 4);
$a->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::SECONDARY_GROUPING_SIZE, 3);
echo $a->format(10005000)`
will produce `1 000 5000`.

Comment: @CBroe, correct. Bulgarian – and I believe Russian, Czech, etc. – only introduce the thousands separator for numbers consisting of 5+ digits. So `5 000` is wrong but `1 200 500` is correct. I was hoping that, in its latest versions (8.x), PHP devs would have taken notice of this fact.

Comment: The actual functionality behind this isn't implemented by the PHP devs themselves, as far as I know, they just provide a PHP "wrapper" that passes this on to some C/C++ library - so it's not really up to them.

Comment: You asked a [similar question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78205860/231316). If they are truly distinct problems, that's fine, but if they are related and can be merged into a single uniform question that would probably be best.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, it is similar only to the extent that the issue is caused by the NumberFormatter class. I'm pretty sure that if I had written about the two separate problems that require separate solutions in one thread, the question would have been closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not likely to be able to do this directly, you can use a wrapper class that modifies the output to what you expect:

```php
class BulgarianNumberFormatter extends \NumberFormatter
{
    public function __construct(
        string|null $locale = 'bg_BG',
        int $style = null,
        string $pattern = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($locale, $style, $pattern);
    }

    public function format(
        int|float $num,
        int $type = self::TYPE_DEFAULT
    ): string|false {
        $numOfWholeDigits = $num != 0 ? floor(log10($num) + 1) : 1;
        $formatted = parent::format($num, $type);
        if($numOfWholeDigits < 6) {
            $formatted = str_replace(
                $this->getSymbol(static::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL),
                '',
                $formatted
            );
        }
        return $formatted;
    }
}
```

To use:

```php
require_once('/path/to/BulgarianNumberFormatter.php');
// or
use Namespace\Of\BulgarianNumberFormatter;

$formatter = new BulgarianNumberFormatter(style:\NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);

$formatter->format(5000);       // 5000
$formatter->format(120500);     // 120 500
$formatter->format(10005000);   // 10 005 000
$formatter->format(3210005000); // 3 210 005 000
```

As a note, the INTL extension is not run directly by PHP. It is a wrapper for the ICU library that is available on just about every system and used for formatting & translation - even by web browsers. If you think this should be changed in the ICU library, you can request changes here: https://icu.unicode.org/bugs

Comment: Thanks, I did request a change. Let's see if it is implemented. I will test your answer soon but it looks like it will do the job. Appreciated!

Comment: This is the error I got when I tried to instantiate this class: `Fatal error: "static::" is not allowed in compile-time constants in C:\wamp64\www\AsphodelWorks.Projects\inc\numformat.class.php on line 16`. I have no idea what this means.

Comment: I replaced `static` with `self` as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792904/constant-in-php-class-and-static-keyword and it worked. I only needed to change `< 6` to `< 5`. I'll now try to figure out how I can change the `GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL` to non-breaking space.

Comment: I added `if($numOfWholeDigits >= 5) { $this->setSymbol(self::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, '&#160;'); } to the `format` function and it appears to be working! Yay!

Comment: Apologies, I forgot `static` is not allowed in that context. Glad you were able to figure it out and modify it to your needs!